# Current 'best approach' for using DbGeogrpahy or SqlGeography in AspNet Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I've read numerous questions on EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1 not supporting Spatial Data yet and read a number of work around's, many of these are 1 year old or older. From what I can read, it appears that it still doesn't support this yet.

I want to ask what the best approach is currently for this situation, as I have a WebApi built on .Net Core 2 which we need to be able to support a number of geolocating functions.

currently we store the Lat/Long of the address, along with a radius they are prepared to travel in the database.

The functionality we would like to achieve is the ability to input a specific location and list the contractors that are able to attend that location. So for example we would call our api with a lat/long of the customer and look to return the contractors that will operate this area based on their lat long + the operating radius.

I have looked at adding the `System.Spatial.Geography` field to the class as a `[NotMapped]` property on the class and then manually adding this to the database (through ef) using the Up migration;

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] ADD [Location] geography");
}
```

However, I then will have to add manual `.FromSql` statements when looking to CRUD the data?

Comment: You could try NHibernate, as that has spatial extensions

Comment: Ok but not sure how that would help with ef and Lina mapping’s in this case?

Comment: I suggest using NHibernate instead of EF